# Differences between .deploy() and deployed() methods

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs, hardhat

I am writing a js script that deploy my solidity contract. In the tuto, they use two methods **.deploy()** and **.deployed()**

```
const main = async () => {
const [owner, randomPerson] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal"); 
const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
await waveContract.deployed();
```

I would like to know what's the difference between these two methods. I can't find any info about **.deployed()** in hardhat documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`deploy()` will trigger this deployment of the contract and `.deployed()` checks if the contract is already available on the blockchain and if the deployment is still ongoing will wait for the deployment transaction to be mined (see https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L819).

Answer (score 0):

From another view point, `deployed()` is just `waveContract.wait()` which is just another function call to wait for some block confirmations

Comment: Hi. I think this should be a comment on the accepted answer, or an edit to the accepted answer, not a answer itself as it does not provide an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`.deployed()` helps us to ensure that our contract is properly deployed and is now ready to interact with further in our script. `.deploy()` handles the actual deployment whereas `.deployed()` will wait for block confirmations too by calling `deployTransaction.wait()` and can also logs error if contract is not deployed (See - https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/1577).

Double checking is always a good practice when it's about deployments and can prevent errors, and that is why I feel `.deployed()` is good to have in the script.